# Disable CSS3 delayed transitions with click/tap events

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, delay

I have a web page with links that look like:

```
<a href="..." class="icon home"><span>Home</span></a>
```

My link is displayed just as an icon (using pseudo elements), but when one hovers over it and waits for some time text also appears beside it. I created these states purely in CSS3 using `transition` delayed state changes.

```
a span {
    text-indent: -1000em;
}

a:hover span {
    text-indent: 0;
    transition: text-indent 0 3s;
}
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/litera/2txVx/) on JSFiddle.

But there are quirks that I'd like to resolve and would be especially happy to do that without Javascript if at all possible:

1. When using a mouse I would like to not show the `span` when user already clicks the action link (does something on page without redirecting elsewhere), because when user clicks the link they likely still stay on it with mouse cursor so delayed hover state still executes.
2. When taping the same link on a mobile device I would like to *unhover* from it so only click would be recorded.

Basically by resolving #2 I would resolve #1 as well when solution isn't device specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it does the trick but you can use `a:active` and `a:visited` to hide the span

```
a:active span{
    display: none;
}

a:visited span{
    display: none;
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2txVx/2/)**

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work. Even your example doesn't seem to work on desktop (tried Chrome browser). And `:active` is only applied as per W3C: **...between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it**. So this doesn't do the trick.